# how to create a django project in windows command promt, i am getting an error of "the system cannot find the the path specified"

Tags: python, django

While creating a django project in windows using command prompt,I created a directory using `mkdir djproject  ->my directory name`. Then when I tried creating a project using `cd project  -> my project name`, I received the error message "the system cannot find the path specified".

```
(myproject) C:\Users\USER>django-admin --version
2.2.1

(myproject) C:\Users\USER>mkdir djproject

(myproject) C:\Users\USER>cd djproject1
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: You make a directory `djproject` but you `cd` to a directory `djproject1`.

Comment: If you want your project name to be `djproject1` then you should be doing `django startproject djproject1`

Answer (score 0):

```
(myproject) C:\Users\USER>django-admin --version
2.2.1

[1](myproject) C:\Users\USER>mkdir djproject <-- You created a directory named djproject

[2](myproject) C:\Users\USER>cd djproject1 
The system cannot find the path specified. <-- This error is caused by [2], 
because you're trying to cd into a directory that does not exist.
```

If you would type `dir` before the `[2]` command, you would see that the only folder is `djproject`. The correct syntax for creating a Django App is:
`django startproject <your_app_name>`